# Godot make item follow mouse

Tags: 2d, mouse, godot, gdscript

I am making a 2D platformer in Godot 3.0 and I want to have the player throw/shoot items using the mouse to aim (similar to bows and guns in Terraria). How would I go about doing this? I am using gdscript.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `look_at()` method (`Node2D` and `Spatial` classes) and `get_global_mouse_position()`:

```
func _process(delta):
    SomeNode2DGun.look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the player position vector from the mouse position and you'll get a vector that points from the player to the mouse. Then you can use the vector's `angle` method to set the angle of your projectiles and normalize the vector and scale it to the desired length to get the velocity.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var Projectile = preload('res://Projectile.tscn')

func _ready():
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
    # A vector that points from the player to the mouse position.
    var direction = get_viewport().get_mouse_position() - position

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('ui_up'):
        var projectile = Projectile.instance()  # Create a projectile.
        # Set the position, rotation and velocity.
        projectile.position = position
        projectile.rotation = direction.angle()
        projectile.vel = direction.normalized() * 5  # Scale to length 5.
        get_parent().add_child(projectile)
```

I'm using a `KinematicBody2D` as the `Projectile.tscn` scene in this example and move it with `move_and_collide(vel)`, but you can use other node types as well. Also, adjust the collision layers and mask, so that the projectiles don't collide with the player.

Comment: There's a short [vector math tutorial](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/math/vector_math.html) in the Godot docs.